# react native paper custom font weight not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I am trying to install custom fonts to a react native paper theme. Looked at the example mentioned on https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/3325 on the snack expo https://snack.expo.dev/@react-native-paper/font-styles-variants

i have implemented the below code after which the components picks up the fontFamily but the fontWeight does not change unless I specify the font family in the StyleSheet.

Can someone suggest what is wrong here.

```
import React from 'react';
import Toast, { BaseToast } from 'react-native-toast-message';
import { McIcon } from '@repo/mobile-ui';
import { Provider as PaperProvider, configureFonts } from 'react-native-paper';

import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { ThemeStatus, srgb } from '@repo/shared/utils';
import { DefaultTheme } from 'react-native-paper';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import AppNavigationShell from '../navigation/AppNavgationShell';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    
  },
};



export const App = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    nsr: require('../../assets/fonts/NunitoSans_10pt-Regular.ttf'),
    nsrBold: require('../../assets/fonts/NunitoSans_10pt-Bold.ttf'),
    nsrItalic: require('../../assets/fonts/NunitoSans_10pt-Italic.ttf'),
    nsrBoldItalic: require('../../assets/fonts/NunitoSans_10pt-BoldItalic.ttf'),
  });

  const baseFont = {
    fontFamily: 'nsr',
  } as const;

  const baseVariants = configureFonts({ config: baseFont });
  const customVariants = {
    displayMedium: {
      ...baseVariants.displayMedium,
      fontFamily: 'nsr',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },

    bold: {
      ...baseVariants.bodyMedium,
      fontFamily: 'nsrBold',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    italic: {
      ...baseVariants.bodyMedium,
      fontFamily: 'nsrItalic',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    boldItalic: {
      ...baseVariants.bodyMedium,
      fontFamily: 'nsrBoldItalic',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
  } as const;

  const mergedFonts = configureFonts({
    config: {
      ...baseVariants,
      ...customVariants,
    },
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={{ ...theme, fonts: mergedFonts }}>
      <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <AppNavigationShell />
        <Toast config={toastConfig} />
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I cried a lot when doing these font related stuff too. The problem in your code is that, the font you are importing is single weight font :

```
nsr: require('../../assets/fonts/NunitoSans_10pt-Regular.ttf'),
```

This `NunitoSans_10pt-Regular.ttf` is a regular weight font, so if you set font weight differently, it won't take any effect.
So what I did was :

You will have 2 conditions -

Either the text will have constant weight, or variable weight.
For constant weight, you can just define `fontFamily` like `nsrBold` or `nsr` according to your `fontWeight` need.
For variable fonts, you can have :

```
fontFamily: weight == 'bold' ? 'nsr' + 'Bold' :
                weight == 'regular' ? 'nsr':
                   'nsrItalic'
```

where `weight` is a useState or variable which defines condition weather text will be bold or regular or whatever you want ( you can add more conditions according to your need )

Don't worry about performance, I have a note app where I used it, and even with 50+ Notes with Title and Content Texts with different fonts and weight, it dosen't lag at all.

That's the way it worked for me, believe me, I spent lot of time figuring out simpler way, but I found nothing. Just use it for now. Hope this works !

( Tip : It can be even better if you would just define a `fontFamily` variable itself, and change it whenever you want to change `fontFamily`  or `fontWeight`, for example if my current font is `NotoSans-Regular` and I wanna make it `NotoSans-Bold`, if will change `setFontFamily('NotoSans-Bold')`, So like changing whole font-family instead of having separate variable for Weight
)